# Need to load initial file every time when restart emacs

Tags: init-file

I'm a newbie in Emacs who just is familiar with basic key bindings. I'm trying to learn more. I just learned to create initial file `~/.emacs.d/init.el` and how to evaluate. But I find I need to load the initial file every time when I restart Emacs. I tried following things:

1. check there is no `~/.emacs` or `~/emacs.el`
2. go to /usr/local/share/emacs/site-lisp, add a code in `subdris.el`

   ```
   (add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/init.el/")
   ```

   And I checked that this file is in `load-path`.

However, I still need to reload the init file every time I restart Emacs. 
Any suggestions?

Comment: You shouldn't need to change any site files to get your init file to load, and there's no point in adding the init file as a directory to the `load-path`, as it won't cause Emacs to load it, but rather to try looking for Elisp files there when someone `require`s something.

Answer (score 4):

Start Emacs and type <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> `user-init-file` <kbd>RET</kbd>

That will tell you the init file which Emacs is actually loading.

<kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(emacs)Init File` <kbd>RET</kbd> will explain in more detail how Emacs establishes which file to load.

I would *guess* that your understanding of `~/` and Emacs' understanding of `~/` are different.

---

> ```
> (add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/init.el/")
> ```

That's incorrect.  `load-path` should be a list of *directories*, not files.  It tells Emacs where to look for libraries.  It does *not* tell Emacs where to find your init file, however; so `load-path` is not relevant to your question.

For clarity, `~/.emacs.d` should be a directory, and `~/.emacs.d/init.el` (if used) should be a regular file within that directory.

Comment: I've tried the command you mentioned and found the init-file in fact is `~/.emacs.d/init.el` . Then I found out I was using the `set backgroud-color` as the simple testing code which does not permanently change the color. Thank you very much for helping me find out the problem and learn more concept about emacs!